# How can I use Twig tempalte to handle label of form input field?

Tags: 8, theming, forms

In a custom module (association), I have a form (MembershipStep3).
I'd like to use Twig template to handle form fields titles and need some advice about that.
In `association.module`, I have this code:

```
function association_theme()
{
  return [
    'association' => [
      'render element' => 'children',
    ],
    'membership_step3' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'membership-step3',
    ],
  ];
}
```

In `MembershipStep3.php`, two almost identical fields are defined this way:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    $form['amap1'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => 'Je souhaite faire partie de l’AMAP (cas 1)',
    ];
    $form['amap2'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
    ];
    some other stuff...
```

And here is `membership-step3.html.twig`:

```
<form{{ attributes }}> {{ form.form_build_id }} {{ form.form_token }} {{ form.form_id }}

<div>

    {{ form.amap1 }}


    <br>
  {{ form.amap2 }}
    <label for="edit-amap2" class="option">
    Je souhaite faire partie de l’AMAP (cas 2)
    </label>

    {# Renders the rest of the form #} {{ form | without('amap1', 'amap2') }}

</div>
```

The result is:
[image]

The generated HTML is:

```
<div>

    <div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-checkbox form-item-amap1 js-form-item-amap1">
        <input data-drupal-selector="edit-amap1" type="checkbox" id="edit-amap1" name="amap1" value="1" class="form-checkbox">

        <label for="edit-amap1" class="option">Je souhaite faire partie de l’AMAP (cas 1)</label>
      </div>



    <br>
  <div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-checkbox form-item-amap2 js-form-item-amap2 form-no-label">
        <input data-drupal-selector="edit-amap2" type="checkbox" id="edit-amap2" name="amap2" value="1" class="form-checkbox">

        </div>

    <label for="edit-amap2" class="option">
    Je souhaite faire partie de l’AMAP (cas 2)
    </label>
```

As you can see, the label for `amap2`is outside of the div created by `{{ form.amap2 }}`.

How can I change my Twig template in order to have a result similar to `amap1`?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal theming engine provides lots of layers. For example there's a twig template for the HTML wrapper (html.html.twig) then a template for the body (page.html.twig) which gets included in the HTML wrapper, then there's body elements which are included in the body template etc.

Forms are also same, there's a general Form wrapper, and when you print `{{ form.amap1 }}` in your `membership-step3.html.twig` this basically includes the `checkboxes.html.twig`, and passes it the `$form['amap1']` array for the details to output.

The answer to your question is - I don't know why you're trying to do this. But the label is already output inside a different twig file, and this form wrapper twig is the wrong place to try and add in field/form element labels. All you need to do to make them look consistent is do what you did for `amap1` - use the `#title` in the form array to specify the label. This way all you need in your `membership-step3.html.twig` file is:

```
<form{{ attributes }}> {{ form.form_build_id }} {{ form.form_token }} {{ form.form_id }}
  <div>{{ form }}</div>
</form> <!-- Don't forget the closing tag -->
```

Tip: Switch on Twig Debug to see where the templates came from straight inside the html output.

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to do this is that I'd like to have all my "language dependent" strings in a specific file (i.e. the Twig template) instead of embedded in the buildForm function of my form.

Comment: You can wrap "translateable" strings in `t()` function and translate them with the Drupal language manager. That's the way to do it if you want translateable strings? So you can do `'#title' => t('Je souhaite faire partie de l’AMAP (cas 1)'),`

Comment: I know that. But I wanted to have the least possible of these in the code of the form.